# Scheduling an email report that runs based on user selected date and time

Tags: node.js, scheduled-tasks, node-cron

I came across these two libraries https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule and https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron.

The user can disable/enable email reports for a scheduled task.The scheduled report can be monthly/weekly/daily.

I save the scheduled timings in the database.But how do i refer a scheduled cron later in future if required to destroy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [crontab](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crontab)

here you can refer to all jobs whenever you want later

```
var cron = require('crontab');

cron.load(function(err, crontab) {        
  // show all jobs 
  var jobs = crontab.jobs();

  // show jobs with conditions 
  var jobs = crontab.jobs({command:'ls -l', comment:/comment 1/});
}
```